# iOS Slide menu with dynamic user image

Tags: ios

I want to make a slide menu in iOS [like](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/0f/ec/92/0fec92d7c7dce13cab0ad94f0c8ab7f4.jpg) this type (Facebook / Pinterst or Gmail app) . I need the user information in Slide menu. I saw a couple of examples,but I can't find any one with user info image. Please give me any suggestion (I have tried it with AMSlideMenu).

Comment: Did you try ECSlidingViewController ? https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController 
You can subclass UITableViewController and add your own custom views and whatnot

Answer (score 3):

I personally use and recommend [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController).

- This is easy and simple to use.
- For image in your slide menu, you have to use UITableView and UITableViewCell with image, by default none of slide menu will provide you this feature.

Do the following:

**Step 1:** Setup PKRevealController to your project
**Step 2:** Make UITableView as your LeftViewController
**Step 3:** Set Image to your UITableView's cell.

[Download Sample Project](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/archive/master.zip)

Answer (score 1):

We use [https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController](http://SWRevealViewController). We use a custom UITableView for this, so you can put any image you like on top of the UITableView or use a header...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy to integrate and smooth slide menu

[BMSlideMenu](https://github.com/beingbarath/BMSlideMenu)

[image: BMSlideMenu]